# Linear Algebra, Linear Transformation problem

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

My task is this

[image]

I am wondering how to go about doing this.

Anyone have ant idea?

Thanks!

Comment: I would encourage you to put more effort into crafting your Questions.  When you post the image of a problem, especially one with multiple parts, with no indication that you've sorted out what about the problem is easy and what is difficult, it gives this Reader a strong impression that you are doing the minimum to get others to do your thinking for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\text{(a)}$ We are looking for a matrix $P = (p_{i j})_{1 \leq i, j \leq 3}$ such that
$$\left \{\begin{array}{c c c c c c c}
p_{1 1} R &+& p_{1 2} G &+& p_{1 3} B &=& I \\
p_{2 1} R &+& p_{2 2} G &+& p_{2 3} B &=& L \\
p_{3 1} R &+& p_{3 2} G &+& p_{3 3} B &=& S
\end{array} \right.$$

Using the formulae given, we deduce that
$$P = \begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{1}{3} & \dfrac{1}{3} & \dfrac{1}{3} \\
1 & -1 & 0 \\
-\dfrac{1}{2} & -\dfrac{1}{2} & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

$\text{(b)}$ Let $R', G', B'$ be the amount of red light, green light and blue light after the light has passed through the sunglasses. We have
$$\left \{\begin{array}{c c c c c c c}
R' &=& R \\
G' &=& G \\
B' &=& 0
\end{array} \right.$$

By doing exactly the same thing as in the previous question, we find
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

$\text{(c)}$ The matrix for the composition of the transformations is simply the product $P A$ (Notice that the matrix corresponding to the first transformation is to the right of the matrix corresponding to the second transformation).

$$P A = \begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{1}{3} & \dfrac{1}{3} & \dfrac{1}{3} \\
1 & -1 & 0 \\
-\dfrac{1}{2} & -\dfrac{1}{2} & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{1}{3} & \dfrac{1}{3} & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 0 \\
-\dfrac{1}{2} & -\dfrac{1}{2} & 0
\end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: Hey man, Thanks for the answer, The question makes alot more sense now. Thanks